# Exponential decay using specific range

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use exponential decay, but the problem for me is how to use a specific range with a max and a min value:

```
const data = []
const x = 6
const max = 20
// const min = 5
for (let index = 1; index <= x; index++) {
    data.push(max / Math.pow(2, index))
}
```

This results in

```
10
5
2.5
1.25
0.625
0.3125
```

But I need exponential decreasing from 20 to 5. How can I set `min`?

Comment: `rate = (max - min) ** (1/steps)`

Comment: The max value is at time = 0.  The min value is the asymtotic limit.  You can get there at different rates.  The function takes the form f(t) = fmin + (fmax-fmin) * exp(-A*t).   You need to pick a value for A, which controls the rate of decay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is probably not what you are looking for but won't a simple if statement do?

```
const data = []
const x = 6
const max = 20
const min = 5
for (let index = 1; index <= x; index++) {
  if(max / Math.pow(2, index)>=min){
    data.push(max / Math.pow(2, index))
  }
}
```

I realize that this has a ton of limitations both on CPU and stack usage since it requires a loop to be ran a ton of times. Also I feel like this is more of a math type problem than a coding one. If I do come up with a reasonable solution I will amend it to this answer. (I mean one using math)

EDIT: I am already working on a math-based answer to this question and have found a probable way to go by it.

EDIT:

using the decay formula, a min should be added by turning max / into something like `min+(max-min)*` as so:

```
const data = []
const x = 6
const max = 20
const min = 5
for (let index = 1; index <= x; index++) {
  if(max / Math.pow(2, index)>=min){
    let decayed = min + (max - min) * Math.pow(0.5, index);
    data.push(decayed);
  }
}
```

So here Math.pow(0.5, index) is going to be the decay constant b, and it is multiplied by the difference of the max and min.
This will give you

```
[12.5, 8.75, 6.875, 5.9375, 5.46875, 5.234375]
```

as the result.

EDIT:
I played around with this a bit more, and if you set x to a high number it will give you a ton of numbers and eventually approach the min:
[image]

EDIT:
OQ posted another similar question:
What do I have to change if I need it the other way round: Fast increasing value and getting slower increasing? Something like wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E0.5 and also with min and max values

Using the model I presented above, I changed the operation a bit, now using natural log to fit the described curve.

[image]
(Graph of ln function)

```
const data = [];
const x = 6;
const max = 20;
const min = 5;

for (let index = 1; index <= x; index++) {
  let increased = min + (max - min) * (1 - Math.exp(-index));
  data.push(increased);
}
```

I accordingly tested again:

[image]
As you can sort of see, the values are about as expected.

(Sorry if my formatting or grammar is a bit off, I am working on a phone)

EDIT:

OQ wanted another system that produces uh not so steep curve. This can be done by having a coefficient of the ln, but adjustments have to be made for the min and max to fit in. Therefore I opted for a negative exponential function that does about the same:

```
const data = [];
const x = 6;
const max = 20;
const min = 5;
const a = 0.2; // Adjust this constant

for (let index = 1; index <= x; index++) {
  let increased = min + (max - min) * (1 - Math.exp(-a * index));
  data.push(increased);
}
```

Adjusting the variable a will change the shape of the curve; use a value like 0.05 for a slight approach

(Sorry if my formatting or grammar is a bit off, I am working on a phone)

Comment: Thank you very much. That is working. What do I have to change if I need it the other way round: Fast increasing value and getting slower increasing? Something like https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E0.5 and also with min and max values

Comment: What I am thinking, you could just reuse this but send the negative of the output, and then for the upper and lower bounds, send the opposite into the function?

Comment: Or you could use a sqrt function

Comment: Wait but that would not have a finite limit… better use natural log instead

Comment: @user3142695 Ok I got a working model I will add an edit

Comment: Thank you. I know, it is a different question, but is it possible to modify the function to get different increasing speed? I mean right now it gets quickly increasing, then there is a "sharp" curve and its keeps increasing, but slowly. Could it be modified, that the initial increasing is a bit slower (adjustable)? Like the orange one: https://www.kapiert.de/media/image/F7E54A14/A051FF45/CA7FD9B8/92F4FD75.png Would be perfect, if I could use a parameter to get different versions...

Comment: Different versions like here: https://www.studienkreis.de/fileadmin/_processed_/b/5/csm_dab8e32ba1_46fb53d242.png

Comment: What about https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pkkunvb8ve

Comment: Change the value of a with the slider, the curve will fit more to that image.

Comment: @user3142695 Ok I added the edit